# How to create a SAS dataset with default values for a column?

Tags: sas

Like in SQL table I would like to create a dataset with default values for some columns. So, when I insert data(other columns except default) in to that table default column should get default value.
Purpose: Basically a SAS process creates SAS dataset structure and a java process receives values from up stream and inserts in to that dataset. If java process didn't receive value for any column then we are trying to populate that column with a default value.
Some thing like this:

```
    create table1 (field1 num,
                   field2 num default 5557,
                   field3 num default 1337, 
                   field4 date default today())

INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field3) VALUES (5, 10);
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (4, 7, 9);

    Output:
    field1 field2 field3 field4
    5      5557   10     17FEB2016
    4      7      9      17FEB2016
```

Comment: Why?  What purpose would it serve?  If you explain the larger problem that is helped by having default values for variables in a dataset then perhaps someone can help you with a method to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

SAS does not support default values for variables in datasets.  But SAS macros do support default values for macro parameters.  You could make a macro that generates the `INSERT` statement for you.

```
%macro add_record
(field1=.
,field2=5557
,field3=1337
,field4=%sysfunc(today())
);
insert into table1 (field1,field2,field3,field4)
 values (&field1,&field2,&field3,&field4)
;
%mend add_record ;
```

So first create your table.

```
data table1;
  length field1-field4 8 ;
  format field4 yymmdd10.;
  stop ;
run;
```

Then you can call the macro within a PROC SQL step to add some records.

```
proc sql ;
  %add_record(field3=10,field1=5);
  %add_record(field1=4,field2=7,field3=9);
quit;
```

And we can view the results with PROC PRINT.

```
proc print data=table1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a default value option within SAS's proc sql.

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Add-SAS-Table-Column-with-Default-Value/td-p/191848

I think your options are going to be either to insert all values, or use some sort of data step.

```
data want;
/*Defaults*/
field1=.;
field2=5557;
field3=1337;
format field4 mmddyy10.;
field4=today();

array fields {3} field1-field3;

/*First Insert*/
field1=5;
field3=10;
output;

/*Reset to original values*/
field1=fields{1};
field2=fields{2};
field3=fields{3};

/*Second Insert*/
field1=4;
field2=7;
field3=9;
output;

run;
```